# Using javacpp-preset/tesseract crashes java on exit

Tags: java, tesseract, javacpp, libgcc

I am trying to use Tesseract to have OCR functionality in a Java application. To achieve this, I am using the Java/Tesseract bridge found [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tesseract).

`pom.xml` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>tesseract</artifactId>
    <version>3.04-1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It works, I can use the library to OCRize an image. But when the Java program finishes, the JVM crashes. For a minimal example, even the very first Tesseract initialization line is enough:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract.TessBaseAPI;

public class MinimalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
        TessBaseAPI tessAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
    }
}
```

If I run this `main`, it gives the following:

```
Hi!

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

And the following error message: `Java(TM) Platform SE binary funktioniert nicht mehr – Windows kann online nach einer Lösung für das Problem suchen.` (`Java(TM) Platform SE binary does not work anymore – Windows can look for a solution to this problem online`).

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   java.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    8.0.650.17
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5614685f
  Fehlermodulname:  libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   0.0.0.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   3f263ec2
  Ausnahmecode: 40000015
  Ausnahmeoffset:   000149a1
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.49
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  7309
  Zusatzinformation 2:  73092f5dbc78923c702ae5601110d2ea
  Zusatzinformation 3:  9fa1
  Zusatzinformation 4:  9fa11625863fb37077a4ab55be352b96
```

I've never had Java crashing before – but I've also never used natives before. ;-) Does anybody have a hint where to look for a solution to this strange behaviour?

**Edit 2015-12-07**: Using [ListDLLs](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx), I've seen that the DLL in question is located in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp3256864312633\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, so "Wrong DLL from `%PATH%`" is not the answer.

Comment: Looks like an issue with MSYS2: http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/mailman/msys2-users/thread/87oat28p6z.fsf@wanadoo.es/  Sounds like this is fixed in the latest version. Would need to rebuild to find out.

Comment: @SamuelAudet: Do I understand this correctly, this would mean, _the Tesseract-Libraries_ would have to be recompiled and the error lies there?

Comment: It looks like the issue lies in the C++ runtime, and we might need to rebuild. Simply replacing `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` with the newest version from MSYS2 might also work.

Comment: Ohhh, I just got it now: `Samiel Audet == saudet`! ;) How could I replace the dll? It lies in a jar that is loaded by Maven, I do not know how I should interfere with that process without sacrifying the whole Maven process benefit.

Comment: Well, try it outside Maven and if it works, we'll figure something out.

Comment: I thought, maybe I could go to my local maven archive and replace the libgcc dll in there with a new one, renew the jar's checksum and give it a try. But I am not able to find that new libgcc file! I've looked for it in the `msys2-base-i686-20150916.tar.xz` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/i686/, but it is not in there. Where can I get it from?

Comment: The latest is in http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/mingw-w64-i686-gcc-libs-5.2.0-4-any.pkg.tar.xz

Comment: Thanks a lot. :-) I've tried it: 1) CRC old dll: `8D4B1312`, CRC new dll: `9F228208`. 2) Injected the new DLL into `leptonica-1.72-1.1-windows-x86.jar` and updated its `.sha1` file. 3) Started debugging the minimal example, used listDLLs: It uses the new dll now. 4) Ended debugging: The exact same crash, only the last two numbers were new (`aee84664081fda1f8a832a07ca541b3c`).

Comment: So I guess we'll need to rebuild from scratch to find out. If you feel up to it, instructions are here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Build-Environments#windows-x86-and-x86_64  And post an issue to make sure I don't forget and test it out later. Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to build it on the computer I want to use it, or can I install all the needed stuff in a virtual machine?

Comment: Sure, virtual machines are fine.

Comment: The issue was never in MSYS2's gcc-libs, but rather in gcc itself, I fixed it in GCC's specs file actually. From an initial investigation a while back, upstream GCC came up with their own fix for it rendering my fix redundant but definitely harmless. I have no idea what javacpp-preset is though; we don't have OpenJDK (if that's a dependency? - external dependencies are unacceptable to us) or javacpp-preset packages in MSYS2 and none of you have approached us with PKGBUILDs so I can't help you properly until that happens (hint hint).

Comment: Okay, now my understanding of what has to be done is fading...

Comment: @Kurtibert We meed to wait until the fix percolates to MSYS2 I guess...

Comment: Okay. I had to look up what "percolate" means, but now I got it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It might have a problem with libwinpthread-1.dll.

Replace current libwinpthread-1.dll in jar with latest mingw32's dll, and it works fine.

1. install msys2-x86_64-20150916.exe downloaded from https://msys2.github.io/ .
2. install base-devel, mingw-w64-i686-toolchain using pacman.
3. extract a leptonica-1.72-1.1-windows-x86.jar, and put all dlls into the same folder of your application.
4. remove leptonica-1.72-1.1-windows-x86.jar from classpath.
5. remove libwinpthread-1.dll from the folder (or replace the libwinpthread-1.dll to installed C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll).
   A path "C:\msys64\mingw32\bin" seems to be loaded first, so if you can install mingw32 ,there is no need to remove(or replace) it.